# Can only post first result of while loop

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop

I am using a while loop to display results from a query. The while loop is working fine. In hidden fields I would like to post the values of userID and accessID to the user details page. I am submitting the form using javascript to submit from a link. My problem is that regardless of the username I click I can only post the values for the first displayed record. What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <form method="post" action="edit_user.php" id="userForm">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" onclick="return(submitForm())"><?php echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['surname']; ?></a> 
            <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="accessID" value="<?php echo $row['accessID']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

The javascript used for submitting the form:

```
function submitForm() {
    var form = document.getElementById("userForm");
    form.submit();
}
```

Thank you.
EDIT - I don't want to pass the values in the url.

Comment: why are you using `<form>` inside while loop ?

Comment: Having a `form` around a `tr` is invalid HTML – either the form has to go into a `td`, or it has to be outside of the complete `table`.

Answer (score 1):

you are generating multiple `<form>`s inside loop, move your `<form>` outside `while` loop, like:

```
<form method="post" action="edit_user.php" id="userForm">
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>       
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['surname']; ?></a> 
            <input type="hidden" name="userID[]" value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="accessID[]" value="<?php echo $row['accessID']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>        
<?php } ?>
<a href="#" onclick="return submitForm();">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but when I do that I only get the values from the last record.

Comment: It works a bit, but I need the values of userID and accessID for only the name selected. What can I do to isolate the results to that?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into trouble because of this line

```
var form = document.getElementById("userForm");
```

In Javascript and HTML, an ID is supposed to be unique to a certain DOM element. In this case, you've got a whole load of form tags that have the same ID. You need to give each form a different ID, and then pass that ID to the submitForm function.

For example:

```
<?php
$id = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>
    $id++;
    <form method="post" action="edit_user.php" id="<?php echo "userForm".$id ?>">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" onclick="return(submitForm("<?php echo "userForm".$id ?>"))"><?php echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['surname']; ?></a> 
            <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="accessID" value="<?php echo $row['accessID']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

and then

```
function submitForm(id) {
    var form = document.getElementById(id);
    form.submit();
}
```

**edit**: how do I php? :D

Comment: When I use this code the link does nothing. Thanks for your effort.