# Only post first result of while loop

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop

I am using a while loop to display results from a query.

The while loop is working fine.

In the hidden field I would like to post the values of **etj12idsinging** to another page.

I am submitting the form from a link using javascript.

The problem is regardless of the row I click, it only posts the first value. What should I do?

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $SIidsinging = $row['etj12idsinging'];
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $SIidnumber; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $SIidtype; ?></td>
    <TD>
        <form method='post' name='form1' id="form1" onclick="submitform()">
            <input type="hidden" name='name2' id='name2' value="<?php echo $row['etj12idsinging']; ?>"></a>
            <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn-warning"/>
        </form>
    </TD>
</tr>
```

The javascript that I used to submit the form:

```
function submitform()
{
    var name2=$('#name2').val();
    window.alert(name2);//it keeps having first result
    $('#form1').submit(); 
}
```

Comment: Please reformulate your question as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Id's have to be unique. That's exactly your problem as the selector will only ever return the first element with the id `name2`/`form1`

Comment: If you want to send all rows by post, i prefer you to create array of input ( like `<input type='hidden' name='fieldname[]' value='your row' />` ). and '<form>' & '</form>' must put on above and below of your **while**.

Comment: @Onilol my problem is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902287/can-only-post-first-result-of-while-loop. I try to follow it but it don't work

Comment: @Andreas know that's the problem. So how to solve that problem?

Comment: @MohammadYekta I do this <form>' & '</form>' must put on above and below of your while but it caused my button don't work at all. Mind to show how to use array of input for my code?

Comment: Why are you messing around with JavaScript at all? Remove the `onclick` part of the `<form />`, change the type of the button from `"button"` to `"submit"` and you're done

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below codes:

```
<?php 
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $SIidsinging = $row['etj12idsinging'];
?>

    <form method='post' name='form1' id="form1" onclick="submitform()">

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $SIidnumber; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $SIidtype; ?></td>
            <TD>

                    <input type="hidden" name='name' value="<?php echo $row['etj12idsinging']; ?>"></a>
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn-warning"/>

            </TD>
        </tr>

    </form>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Now in your result of post, you can get this array, by:

```
<?php
    $names = $_POST[ 'name' ];
?>
```

Comment: if i put <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn-warning"/> outside the while scope then i will only have 1 button for more than 1 query result when I needed the button for every result?

Comment: It doesn't work, the button isn't even run the function. When i move the <form> above <input> it runs the function but it still only return the first result when i keep id="name2" on the input tag

Comment: You want to show hidden value only on alert  message, if you want. please tell me to i change above code for solve this problem.

Comment: I am really sorry, i have that alert to know the value that being post to other pages if its still return just the first result or not.

Comment: no problem :) , i got your means. you must remove **id** and **onsubmit** from `<form>` tag, because in your javascript, you set `var name2=$('#name2').val();` . ID in pages, can set only one time, and when you call this, you get only first value.

Comment: Yes, i know what's the problem with my code. But I don't know how to solve it. Hmm.. do you know how to change my code so it works?

Comment: please change type of button to submit -> `<input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn-warning"/>` to `<input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn-warning"/>` . now your form will post by clicking on submit button

Comment: Hy it works, but i did some changed on your code

<input type="hidden" name='name[<?php $SIidnumber; ?>]' value="<?php echo $row['etj12idsinging']; ?>">
to
<input type="hidden" name='name' value="<?php echo $row['etj12idsinging']; ?>">

<?php
    $names = $_POST[ 'name[]' ];
?>

to

<?php
    $names = $_POST[ 'name' ];
?>

Comment: hmmmm, yes you can use string instead of array for getting post form :)